Clip images In QGIS Layout Composer
Using this video: YouTube video of tutorial
I was able to clip a map in a circular shape. I want to do the same procedure for the images.


You could use another software than QGIS to clip it to a circular shape (or rather making the edges transparent). I would recommend using GIMP and follow this tutorial. This will make the image appear circular:


You can just load your image as a raster layer, and create a theme with only this image.
